# what if i remove .config file from the linux source

Tags: 12.04, kernel, compiling

I was just curious whether i can remove the .config file.
Actually i am learning how to edit the config (from make menuconfig) and recompile the kernel. So if i remove the .config file from the source (/usr/src/linux) how does it affect? I am learning from [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-customize-your-ubuntu-kernel/)

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the .config file then you'll have to start the kernel configuration from total scratch (selecting the architecture and so on). There is also the possibility to start with a "default configuration" by using the

> make XXXX_defconfig

Where XXXX is the system you are working on (for example i386). This default configurations are found in *arch/XXX/configs* directories (with XXX being the architecture).

Also some environment/Makefile settings are used from the kernel to assist you in this process (for example the ARCH variable is used to filter out the architectures proposed)